# header not being responsive when resizing

Tags: html, css, jstl, responsive

I have a table where when I resize it wont show my header `Steps` on the web view it does show perfectly - but when I resize I don't get to see my Steps header. is there way to fix this in my code below with css or jstl/jsf tags? thanks for the help. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1vV0.jpg

Image appears: 
[image]

here is my code:

```css
table {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

thead th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

/* You will need to display:none the duplicated header in responsible-table-item*/

tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
    display: none;
}

/* Add screen proportion or class when break occurs */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Hide table headers */
    .table-header {
        display: none;
    }

    tr.responsive-table-item {
        display: block;
    }

    tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    tr.responsive-table-item td:first-child {
        background-color: #ccc;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    tr.responsive-table-item td,
    tr.responsive-table-item th {
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc(50% - 22px);
        /* Cell Border + padding*/
        word-break: break-all;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-header"> 
            <th></th>

            <c:forEach var="stepNumber" begin="1" end="#{testBean.jobEntity.stepSize}" varStatus="loop">
                <c:if test="${loop.index lt 9}"> 
                    <th  class="responsive-table-cell">Step #{stepNumber}</th>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>


        <c:forEach items="#{testBean.jobEntity.jobRows}" var="jobRow"> 
            <tr class="responsive-table-item">
                <td class="left-header">#{jobRow.rateType}</td>

                <c:forEach items="#{jobRow.steps}" var="step" varStatus="loop">
                    <c:if test="${loop.index lt 8}"> 
                    <th class="left-header">#{step.amount}</th>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: So if you create a static table without jstl (effectively this is not jsf related) it works?

Comment: however, it does with a static table.I can show you a static way if you like - but, I want to use it the code I have above.

Comment: Then look at the **differences** in the **client-sIde html**  between a statically created table and the jstl based one. Should not be too difgicult and most likely not jstl related either. And post all the relevant info in the question

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my answer:**

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

thead th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}



tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
  display: none;
}

   
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .table-header {
    display: none;
  }

  tr.responsive-table-item {
    display: block;
  }

  tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  tr.responsive-table-item td:first-child {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  tr.responsive-table-item td,
  tr.responsive-table-item th {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
   
    word-break: break-all;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-header">
      <th></th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 1</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 2</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 3</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 4</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 5</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 6</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 7</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $57.36</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $58.94</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $60.56</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $62.23</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $65.70</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $69.37</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $73.23</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $77.31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,588.80</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,715.20</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,844.80</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,978.40</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,256.00</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,549.60</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,858.40</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $6,184.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $119,767.68</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $123,066.72</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $126,449.28</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $129,936.24</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $137,181.60</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $144,844.56</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $152,904.24</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $161,423.28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `width: 13%` in left-header class

```
left-header{
width: 13%;
font-weight:normal;
color:#039;
border-right:2px solid #6678b1;
padding:10px 8px;
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: it showing ok, but the steps are missing while in mobile view.

Comment: wait. now I hard-refreshed and my table looks bigger like this: https://imgur.com/a/2EEGP7X

Comment: I think the best will be with `media-queries` , no?

Comment: the css works, but on desktop view the numbers are not showing and also on the mobile view the steps are not showing properly.

Answer (score -1):

When the table starts looking bad try media queries for e.g. :

```
@media all and (max-width: XXXpx){
here you need to put new css styles for example ( smaller font or sthg)
}
```